# Graphe of a continuous function

Tags: general-topology

How to prove that if F is Hausdorff and $f: E\rightarrow F$ is continuous

the complement of $G(f)$ is open, $G(f)=\{(x,f(x)), x\in E\}$

Without using the diagonal $\Delta$ i want to deduce that G(f) is closed

Edit: If i take $(x,y)\in C_{E\times F} G(f)$ this means that $y\neq f(x)$ as $F$ is Hausdorff there exists two opens $U$ and $V$ such that $f(x)\in U$ and $x\in V$ and $U\cap V=\emptyset$

As $f$ is continuous we have that $W=f^{-1}(U)$ is open containing $x$

We see that $W\times V \cap G(f)\subset \{(x,f(x)), x\in W, f(x)\notin U\}=\emptyset$ then $(x,y)\in W\times V \subset (E\times F)\setminus G(f)$

Thank you .

Answer (score 1):

You know that $F$ is hausdorff $\iff$ $\Delta =\{(x,x)\mid x\in F\}$ is closed (if not, prove it !). Since $g:=f\times id_F:(x,y)\longmapsto (f(x),y)$ is closed in $E\times F$ and that $G(f)= g^{-1}(\Delta )$, you got your result.

Comment: I don't want to use $\Delta$ i want to prove that the complement is open and then deduce that the graphe is closed